# Assign single line json element to label in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, json

I'm trying to assign a simple json feed element to a label. 
My json feed that looks like this:

```
[{"code":501,"data":{"req":"0"}}]
```

My code after I've retrieved it from a url:

```
 NSURLResponse *response;
 NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
 NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[POSTReply bytes] length:[POSTReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"Reply: %@", theReply);

 NSArray* json_object = [NSJSONSerialization
                       JSONObjectWithData:POSTReply
                       options:0
                       error:nil];
 NSArray *json_object_line = [json_object objectAtIndex:0];
 mainLabel.Text= [json_object_line valueForKey:@"code"];
```

There is no way I can get this to work. The app simply crashes unless I remove the last 2 lines. I've tried a lot of other options (especially for the last 2 lines) to no avail.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried to assign `NSNumber` to the label's `text` property. It's a reason of the crash. The proper way is to get a formatted string from JSON field:

```
 NSURLResponse *response;
 NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                           returningResponse:&response error:nil];
 NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:POSTReply.bytes
                                               length:POSTReply.length
                                             encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

 NSArray* json_object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:POSTReply
                                                        options:0
                                                          error:nil];
 NSDictionary *json_object_line = json_object[0];
 mainLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", json_object_line[@"code"]];
```

Comment: Thanks Igor, it didn't work directly but once I corrected to    `mainLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [json_object_line valueForKey:@"code"]];` it did

Comment: There's no difference between `[json_object_line valueForKey:@"code"]` and `json_object_line[@"code"]`. Just the last is a newer syntax.

Comment: You've also mistaken with type of `json_object_line`. It should be `NSDictionary`, not `NSArray`. See updated answer above.